# What is the point of finding the area under the curve?

Tags: calculus

I am learning calculus and am at the point where we switch from differentiation to integration.  What is the point of finding the area of a certain graph under the curve?
So far I do understand and am learning how to find the area under the curve using Riemann sums but my teacher is not clear on what the point of it is.

Comment: Was your teacher any more clear on what is the point of finding the slope of a tangent line to a curve?

Comment: @Jatt It seems like you don't have a good teacher, which is generally a problem in your country unfortunately. You can't help it of course...In addition to the answers to others, here is my contribution: The integral is also used to calculate the length of a curve from one point on the curve to another. I hope you understand that this is very useful in math as well as in its application.

Answer (score 5):

The area under a curve is its integral.  Many *many* physical, chemical, financial, and other variables are related by such integration.  For instance if you have a speed as a function of time ($v(t)$), you can find the position $x(t)$ (up to a constant) by integrating the speed.

Comment: In other words, if you know where you started, and you know the history of your speed, you can find out where you are now.

Comment: ... as just one of a gazillion examples.  The total volume of water poured into a bucket is the integral over time of the *rate* at which the water is poured.  And so on....

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, it's applications are truly numerous, and one can keep coming up with examples-besides of course the fact that it can simply be fun and challenging to find technics to compute certain integrals-like all math can be.
 
That said, may I suggest you check this "famous" example of a very specific integral,
 the Gaussian Integral: $\int\nolimits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm dx=\sqrt{\pi}$ 
The variety of natural problems associated with it is astounding.